# RecyclerView, видя два одинаковых подряд объекта, автоматически смещает "камеру" на второй, оставляя впередиидущий сверху вне поля видимости

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, mvvm, rxjava

In the Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

    private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var currentWord :Word
    private val drillerAdapter = DrillerAdapter()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding = CardstackLayoutBinding.bind(view)
        viewModel.getLivedataList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    drillerAdapter.submitList(it)
                    Log.d(TAG, "drlr workWorkList.size = " + it.size)
                }
        val drillerLayoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager(requireContext(), this)
        binding.apply {
        cardStackView.apply {
            layoutManager = drillerLayoutManager
            adapter = drillerAdapter
            itemAnimator = null // ХЗ НАДО ЛИ
        }
    }
    viewModel.get4words()
}

override fun onCardSwiped(direction: Direction?) {
        if (direction == Direction.Bottom) {
            currentWord.shown = false
            viewModel.update(currentWord)
        }
        viewModel.removeAndAddWord(currentWord)
        Log.d(TAG, currentWord.foreign + " is removed. (drlr)")
    }
override fun onCardAppeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
    currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCardAppeared: " + currentWord.foreign + " IS NOW currentWord, position in adapter - " + position + " (drlr)")
}
override fun onCardDisappeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
    currentWord = drillerAdapter.getWordAt(position)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCardDisappeared: " + currentWord.foreign + " IS NOW currentWord, position in adapter - " + position + " (drlr)")
}
```

Метод removaAndAddWord во ViewModel:

```
fun removeAndAddWord(word: Word) {
        mList = ArrayList<Word>(mList)
        mList.remove(word)
        Log.d(TAG, "(drlr) removeAndAddWord: mList.size =  " + mList.size)
        m1word.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<Word> {
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    composite.add(d)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(t: Word) {
                    mList.add(t)
                    mLivedataList.value = mList
                    Log.d(TAG, "(drlr) removeAndAddWord called, now mList contains: ")
                    mList.forEach { item -> Log.d(TAG, "(drlr) " + item.foreign) }
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    // empty
                }

            })
    }
```

Наблюдения:

1. когда в листе 2 айтема с одним значением подряд, то при методе remove ресайклВью странным образом остается тот, что стоял на позиции 0, а ресайклВью смещается на позицию один, оставляя нулевой item сверху, за полем видимости.)
2. Это происходит, когда именно 2 подряд одинааковых слова. Вью, когда топ-позицию занимает одно из них, а второе стоит прямо под ним, перемещается сразу на второе, а первое остается "выше" за пределами вью (но остается и в листе, и какбы учтено в адаптере, поскольку если эта "пробка" рассасывается (т.е. следующие Word-ы приходят все разные), то потом вью возвращается на эту первую пропущенный айтем.
3. Чем меньше в базе слов, тем чаще позиция адаптера смещается с 0й на 1юи далее. Если свайп сделан вниз (см onSwipe()), то Word.shown делается false, и это слово больше не появится (метод get1word берет только слова с shown=true из базы)), и тогда чем меньше слов включенных, тем чаще повторы в рабочем листе, и больше таких "пробок". CardStackView доходит "до дна" и экран становится пустым, хотя сверху есть неудаленные слова.

Мне нужно понять, почему View, видя два одинаковых подряд объекта, автоматически смещает "камеру" на второй, и как жто вылечить.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Весь код Адаптера:

```
class DrillerAdapter() : ListAdapter<Word, DrillerAdapter.DrillerViewHolder>(DrillerDiff()) {


    inner class DrillerViewHolder(private val binding: CardstackItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        binding.root
    ) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != CardStackView.NO_POSITION) {
                        tvNativ.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(word: Word) {
            binding.apply {
                tvForeign.text = word.foreign
                tvNativ.text = word.nativ
                tvNativ.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrillerViewHolder {
        val binding = CardstackItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return DrillerViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrillerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    fun getWordAt(position: Int): Word {
        return getItem(position)
    }

    class DrillerDiff : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word) =
            oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word) =
            oldItem.foreign == newItem.foreign && oldItem.nativ == newItem.nativ
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше весь адаптер покажите! Проблема с отображением в RV исключительно из-за плохого описания состояния `view` объектов в адаптере. Если вы отображаете что-то по условию, значит не описали состояние объекта в `else` и тд и тп...

Comment: добавил весь код адаптера